# Android WebView was working and now it's not!

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Alright everyone see if you can believe this.  Two android applications both have webviews and both worked.  Now they don't, web page not available.  Fresh VM dev environments (Ubuntu Natty and Mkat) with the most recent ADT and SDK as of this post.  I follow the HelloWebView tutorial(http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) and experience similar results, web page not available.  I can confirm that the emulator does have access to the internet and I have gone as far installing debug and release apks on a physical device with no luck.  I promise in each situation my Internet Permissions are in the right place :)  I've looked all over without any luck.  Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this to see if issue is with internet connection or WebView itself.

```
wv.loadData("<html><body>test</body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

wv is your WebView.

Answer (score 0):

If the webview were working before and you didnot make any change and its not working now, that menas the issue may be with the URl. Can you open that url from your browser to see whether it is working or not. Can we know those urls?

Thanks
Deepak